# Click checkbox with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to click the checkbox 'HIV/AIDS' on this url: `https://www.unodc.org/ngo/showExtendedSearch.do` using RSelenium

This is my code so far:

```
#load library
library(RSelenium)

#Check for serves and start server
RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()

#Specify remote driver
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(browserName='firefox')

#new remotedriver using default initialisation values
remoteDriver$new()

#Initialise session 
remDr$open()

#navigate to advanced search page

url <- "https://www.unodc.org/ngo/showExtendedSearch.do"
remDr$navigate(url)

#Click 'HIV/AIDS' filter
button <- remDr$findElements("name","HIV/Aids")

button$clickElement()
```

It goes wrong at finding the element of checkbox 'HIV/AIDS'. I now get an empty list in return. I tried using selectorgadget which lead to following code:

```
button <- remDr$findElements("css selector",'#applicationArea > form > table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > input[type="checkbox"]')
button$clickElement()
```

This time I did not get an empty list, but also not the desired webelement.

It would really helpful if somebody could help.

EDIT: my last code (using css selector) seems to work for other people. I, however, get following error: `attempt to apply non-function`, so something else has to be wrong.

Comment: I get the same error as with `remDr$findElements("name","areaAidshiv")`: 'attempt to apply non-function'. So I assume the mistake lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've got worked for me:

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

url <- "https://www.unodc.org/ngo/showExtendedSearch.do"
remDr$navigate(url)

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', 
                             value = '#applicationArea > form > table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(7) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > input[type="checkbox"]')

webElem$clickElement()
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error 'attempt to apply non-function', which is new to me. What could be wrong?

Comment: @user3387899 I don't really have any good suggestion.  Maybe try clearing your environment and starting fresh, just with this bit of code?

Comment: Ok, I simply copied and pasted your code and now it works... So it must have something do with the additional pieces of code I used like `checkForServer` etc. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user3387899 yes I've  had issues with those server functions in the past too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
button <- remDr$findElements("name","areaAidshiv")
button$clickElement()
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried it earlier but this gave me the error 'attempt to apply non-function'.